# Analysis: Calculate the Taylor Series and determine radius and interval of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

This is the function: $f(x)=e^{3x}$ and I am required to calculate it's Taylor series about $a=-2$.

I am also required to determine the radius and interval of convergence of the resulting power series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We start by calculating that $\space f^{(n)}(x) = 3^ne^{3x}\space$ for $\space n\geqslant0$, and so $f^{(n)}(-2)=3^ne^{-6}$. Hence, the Taylor series for $f$ entered at $a=-2$ is

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}f^{(n)}(-2)(x+2)^2=e^{-6}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{3n}{n!}(x+2)^n.$$

The radius of convergence of this series is $\infty$ and so the interval of convergence is $\mathbb{R}$.